# TSX & State member differences

Tags: typescript, atom-editor, typescript1.5

I am new to the entire ecosystem and I wonder why in my example component inside the **render** function `this.state.displayedListItems` is an array of strings, as expected, but inside the **filterList** function `this.state.displayedListItems` is undefined?

I am using

```
Atom 1.0.2 (https://atom.io/)
atom-typescript 5.0.29 (https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript),

tsd 0.6.3 with
"react/react.d.ts": { "commit": "a9c59f8166b4d7f1e8c4309a506987c2e6d78b5e"},
"react/react-jsx.d.ts": {"commit": "a9c59f8166b4d7f1e8c4309a506987c2e6d78b5e"}

OSX Yosemite 10.10.4
```

Here is my demo component (mount it and type a letter in the search-box to get an 'undefined' inside an alert) [notice that you have to scroll the following code block below to see the entire code]

```
/// <reference path="../typings/react/react.d.ts" />

interface FilterListTestPropsInterface
{}

interface FilterListTestStateInterface
{
  completeListItems : string[];
  displayedListItems : string[];
}

class FilterListTestState implements FilterListTestStateInterface
{
  completeListItems : string[];
  displayedListItems : string[];
  constructor(allItems: string[], displayedItems: string[])
  {
    this.completeListItems = allItems,
    this.displayedListItems = displayedItems
  }
}

class FilterListTest extends React.Component<FilterListTestPropsInterface, FilterListTestStateInterface>
{
  constructor(props:FilterListTestPropsInterface)
  {
    super(props);
  }

  // hardcoded values for testing/exploration purpose
  initialState : FilterListTestStateInterface =
  {
    completeListItems : ["Apples", "Broccoli", "Chicken", "Duck", "Eggs", "Fish", "Granola", "Bash Brownies"],
    displayedListItems : []
  }

  componentWillMount()
  {
    this.setState(new FilterListTestState(this.initialState.completeListItems, this.initialState.completeListItems));
  }

  filterList(event : React.SyntheticEvent) //used event:any then event.constructor.name to find the type
  {
alert(this.state + ' ' + this.state.displayedListItems); // debug result is object + undefined
    var input : HTMLInputElement = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    var updatedList = this.state.completeListItems.filter
    (
      function(item)
      {
        return item.toLowerCase().search(input.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
      }
    );
    this.setState
    (
      {
        completeListItems : this.initialState.completeListItems,
        displayedListItems : updatedList
      }
    );
  }

// here, state this.state.displayedListItems has the right values
  render()
  {
    return (
      <div className="filter-list">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" onChange={this.filterList}/>
        <FilterableList items={this.state.displayedListItems}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class FilterableList extends React.Component<any, any>
{
  constructor(props:any)
  {
    super(props);
  }

  render()
  {
    return (
      <ul>
      {
        this.props.items.map
        (
          function(item)
          {
            return <li key={item}>{item}</li>
          }
        )
       }
      </ul>
    );
  }
};

// mount this into a html doc with something like
// React.render(<FilterListTest/>,  document.getElementById('ReactContent'));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Common error. It is because of the way `this` works in JavaScript

## Fix

Change `filterList(event : React.SyntheticEvent) {` to `filterList = (event : React.SyntheticEvent) => {`

More: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA and http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html

Comment: Awesome, thank you. (p.s. if that is so common, would be good if the compiler could give a warning)

Comment: `this` in JavaScript ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯.